# Devexpress Editor TextEdit can't bind XCT UserStopTypingBehavior in Xamarin Forms App

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, devexpress, xamarin-community-toolkit

I want to use Devexpress Editor TextEdit but I can not bind this to XCT *UserStoppedTypingBehavior*

I'm usng this code below :

```
 <dxe:TextEdit
                 Margin="2"
                 LabelText="Evrak Seri"
                 LabelFontSize="16"
                 LabelColor="Black"
                 IsVisible="{Binding EvrakSeriSiraGorunum}"
                 BackgroundColor="White"
                 BorderColor="Black"
                 WidthRequest="300" 
                 Text="{Binding EvrakseriText}"
                 ReserveBottomTextLine="True"
                 IsLabelFloating="False"
            x:Name="evrakSeriText1"
            
            >
                <dxe:TextEdit.Behaviors>
                        <xct:UserStoppedTypingBehavior Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" />
                    </dxe:TextEdit.Behaviors>
                    <dxe:TextEdit.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="dxe:TextEdit" Value="-1" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference evrakSeriText1},
                                   Path=Text.Length}" >

                            

                        </DataTrigger>


                    </dxe:TextEdit.Triggers>
                </dxe:TextEdit>
```

The error is :
**System.InvalidOperationException Message=bindable not an instance of AssociatedType**
I think this "TargetType" is wrong but I can not find the true one.

Is this textedit have anything like *xct:UserStoppedTypingBehavior* ? If it's not, how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an similar issue on the devexpress support center for the maui. You can check the [TextEdit with .NET MAUI Community Toolkit](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1106542/textedit-with-net-maui-community-toolkit).

And I also checked the source code in the xamarin: The [EditBase Class](https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/DevExpress.XamarinForms.Editors.EditBase) inherit the **View** Class, but the [UserStoppedTypingBehavior](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/Behaviors/UserStoppedTypingBehavior.shared.cs) can only be attached to elements that inherit **InputView**.

You can use the [EditBase.Completed Event](https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/DevExpress.XamarinForms.Editors.EditBase.Completed) to do what you want .

Comment: Thanks for good advices. If this TextEditor can not use _xct:UserStoppedTypingBehavior_ I can not use it. My app based on this property.